# How do I output a formula's result inside double quotes?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, double-quotes

This is a very basic question, sure the answer will be straightforward but cannot see any solution on the web so far...

Basically, I got this type of formula:

`=IF(E314="AV",...,...)`

If this statement is true, I want the result to be written between double quotes i.e. "-" 
in the cell.

I have tried this:

`=IF(E314="AV",""-"","")`

But it does not work out. How should I be doing it?

Many thanks in advance! Cheers!

Comment: you were close: `=IF(e314="AV","""-""","something else")`

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to concatenate with explicit " characters

```
=CONCATENATE(CHAR(34),"hello",CHAR(34))
```

So in your case...

```
=IF(e314="AV",CONCATENATE(CHAR(34),"-",CHAR(34)),"")
```

EDIT: Another solution

```
=IF(e314="AV","""-""","")
```